# Error when try to use WITH inside CASE (VALUE IN ) Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is my snippet code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SME_PFGL"."UFN_GET_SECTOR_RATING"
    (
    L_RATING_ID NUMBER
    )
    RETURN CHAR
    IS
    L_RATSELWAS VARCHAR (20);
    BEGIN
        SELECT LISTAGG(RATING_ID,',') 
            WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RATING_ID) into L_RATSELWAS
            FROM SME_MSDT.IC_RATING;

        CASE 
            WHEN L_RATING_ID IN (WITH DATA AS (SELECT L_RATSELWAS STR FROM DUAL)
                                            SELECT TO_NUMBER(TRIM(COLUMN_VALUE)) STR
                                            FROM DATA, XMLTABLE(STR))
            THEN RETURN 'Y';
        END CASE;
    END;
```

But i got an error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WITH" when expecting one of the following:
>   ( - + case mod new not null select

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the logic that you are trying to implement here? I don't see any need of the `XMLTABLE` here

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly check for the existence of the `RATING_ID` in the table and return the result accordingly as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SME_PFGL"."UFN_GET_SECTOR_RATING" (
    L_RATING_ID NUMBER
) RETURN CHAR IS
    L_RATSELWAS   CHAR(1); -- changed data type
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END
    INTO L_RATSELWAS
    FROM
        SME_MSDT.IC_RATING
    WHERE
        RATING_ID = L_RATING_ID;

    RETURN L_RATSELWAS;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you meant to do, you'd like to return `Y` if `l_rating_id` (function's parameter) exists in `ic_rating` table. If so, here's one option:

```
create or replace function ufn_get_sector_rating
  (l_rating_id in number)
return char
is
  retval char(1) := 'N';
begin
  select max('Y')
    into retval
    from ic_rating
    where rating_id = l_rating_id;

  return retval;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return retval;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

When determining is something exists I tend to just use "if exists" whenever I can. This seems, at least to me, much more descriptive of what I am trying to do. So perhaps:

```
create or replace function  ufn_get_sector_rating (
    l_rating_id number
) return varchar2 
is
    l_ratselwas   varchar2(1) := 'N'; 
begin
    select 'Y'
      into l_ratselwas
      from dual
     where exists 
           (select null 
              from sme_pfgl.ic_rating
             where rating_id = l_rating_id 
           ) ; 
    return l_ratselwas;
exception 
when no_data_found then
     return l_ratselwas;
end;
```

Whether you use this approach or not I would suggest:

1. Do not use char data type. It provides no advantage over varchar2, but often introduces unexpected results.
2. Do not double quote object names.